# HTML Links pointing to current browser URL

Tags: html, url, browser, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to create simple links using . I have a page just containing some video tags, some text, and some links. The web browser is treating all the links on the page as links to links t the current URL (ie. just refreshing the current page). No matter what I change the link to, it always just refreshes the page. Links on other pages work just fine, it's just this one page.

If the browser's current URL is http://www.my_domain_name.com/Folder/index.html and I have a `<a href ="http://www.example.com/cake">Link</a>` the link just reloads the page. When I hover over the link, the browser says it points to the current page. When I view page source, the link is correct in the HTML code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Kindly provide a short example code so that we could understand your point

Comment: Check carefully to see if all elements on the form have had their tags closed properly.  I've occasionally encountered weird behavior on a page because of an unclosed tag (it can be as simple as a missing `>` character).